# Scanner detect end of file Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read in data from a text file and inserting it into an array, one line gap in the file means that a new array will be created. Two lines and the scanner should be closed. Here is the text file:

```
`Test
test
test
Telephone
Cardiology

Test Doctor 2
Test
20 Test
Telephone
Cardiology
`


  public Object[][] readData() throws FileNotFoundException{
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("DoctorRecordsFile.txt"));
  String line;
  int emptyFile = 0 ;

  int i = 0;
  int x = 0;
  String[][] doctor = new String[100][5];
  while (emptyFile <= 1){
  line = sc.nextLine() ;

  if ((!line.isEmpty())){
        doctor[i][x] = line;
        System.out.println(doctor[i][x]);

        x++;
        emptyFile = 0;   
  }
  else{
      System.out.println("PRE call emptyFile: " + emptyFile);
       emptyFile++;
      System.out.println("Post call emptyFile: " + emptyFile);
    if(emptyFile >= 2){
       sc.close();
    }
    else{
       i++;
       x = 0;
    }
    }
  }
  return new Object[][]{doctor[0]};
```

The actual result I expect is that the scanner will close and stop reading in data, here are my console errors:

```
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at medicalsystem.ReadInDoctors.readData(ReadInDoctors.java:35)
    at medicalsystem.MainMenu.View_Doctor_ButtonActionPerformed(MainMenu.java:193)
```

Comment: you can simply look for a line that only contains new line

Comment: Is the content of your text file between the accent marks? I don't see two empty lines in the text file. You need to check if there is a next line with hasNextLine().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see two empty lines in your text file. How about checking if your input file has another line to read? Something like the following:

```
while (emptyFile <= 1) {

            if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                line = sc.nextLine();

                if ((!line.isEmpty())) {
                    doctor[i][x] = line;
                    System.out.println(doctor[i][x]);

                    x++;
                    emptyFile = 0;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("PRE call emptyFile: " + emptyFile);
                    emptyFile++;
                    System.out.println("Post call emptyFile: " + emptyFile);
                    if (emptyFile >= 2) {
                        sc.close();
                    } else {
                        i++;
                        x = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Notice I wrapped your code in an if statement: "if (sc.hasNextLine()) {"

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BpBuU6Zx This is what I've come to now, it creates an infinite loop and never shuts down crashing my program(Not too sure how to use StackOverFlow and it said my comment was too long if I inserted the code.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for this?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()

It should be included in your while statement. This way you would not need the `emptyFile`variable.